# Why i cant delete data from arrays more than one? React Native

Tags: react-native

I want to delete item from array object base of selected checkboxes. But when I try to delete by id, it's only delete one object.

```
const [datas, setData] = useState([]); <-- i already setData(Data)

const deleteItemById = (id) => { << ----------- Something wrong with this code
        const filteredData = datas.filter(item => item.id !== id);
        setData(filteredData);
        console.log(datas)
    }
```

```
const selectedID = () =>{
    --- Some API Post Method ---
    --- example id_kunjungan is array and contain ["1","2"] from selected checbox
        for (var i = 0; i < id_kunjungan.length; i++){
             deleteItemById(id_kunjungan?.[i]) <<------- this return the id 
             console.log(id_kunjungan?.[i]) 
        }

}
```

```
const Data= [
    {
        "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
        "id": "1",
        "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
        "hari": "Saturday",
    },
{
        "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
        "id": "2",
        "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
        "hari": "Saturday",
    },
{
        "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
        "id": "3",
        "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
        "hari": "Saturday",
    },
{
        "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
        "id": "4",
        "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
        "hari": "Saturday",
    },
];
```

I already check for loop its run 2 times but the id[2] is not deleted, it only deletes the first id, not the second or third or more. Why this is happened? Or what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your code and you are using a for-loop to update the state, which mean states may not be updated correctly since you are updating states many times at one go, overwriting each update.

```
// This code is wrong ❌
  for (var i = 0; i < id_kunjungan.length; i++){
       deleteItemById(id_kunjungan?.[i]) // you are calling setDatas multiple times here which is wrong.
       console.log(id_kunjungan?.[i]) 
  }
```

You can try doing just

```
deleteItemByIds(id_kunjungan) // <--- send the entire array of Ids
```

Then modify your deleteItemByIds function to remove all items whose id matches.

```
const deleteItemByIds = (ids = []) => { // <<-- array of ids e.g. [1,2,3,4,5]
        const filteredData = datas.filter(item => !ids.includes(item.id);
        setData(filteredData);
        // console.log(datas) // <--- ❌ Remove this. this will not give u the latest state because state updating is async 
}
```

If you want to see the state change, add a `useEffect` block.

```
useEffect(() => {
   console.log('datas', datas); //console log whenever datas changes.
}, [datas])
```

Comment: Nice, thanks this code is what I wanted, finally get rid `for-loop`.  thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
const Data= [
{
    "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
    "id": "1",
    "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
    "hari": "Saturday",
},
{
    "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
    "id": "2",
    "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
    "hari": "Saturday",
},
{
    "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
    "id": "3",
    "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
    "hari": "Saturday",
},
{
    "start": "2022-01-01 10:35:08",
    "id": "4",
    "tanggal": "01-01-2022",
    "hari": "Saturday",
},
];

const deleteItems = (idsToDelete) => {
    const newData = Data.filter((item) => {
    return !idsToDelete.includes(item.id)
  })
  return newData
} 

console.log(deleteItems(['1','2']))  // <--- pass the ids to delete here
```

Comment: it still deletes only the first one, second and the other are not deleted.

Comment: `console.log(newData)` they're returning the same values after the first ids

Comment: Can you explain what do you refer to when you say `values after first ids`

Comment: Example, I got 4 values and select 2 values from checkboxes. When deleting values by `id`. The first deletion should remain 3 values, and then the second deletion should return 2 values. But when I try, second deletion is same as first deletion (it's not deleting value after first one)

Answer (score -1):

Using `Splice` make it easier. Using id for finding index of array, and splice it.

```
    const deleteItemById = (id) => {
        setData((prevState) =>{
            const index = prevState.map(function(x) {return x.id; }).indexOf(id);
            const filteredData = prevState.splice(index, 1);
            return [...prevState]
        })
    }
```